# GETTING 404 Result on javascript face-api problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, web

Hello everyone i try to use face-api but getting error on this image
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtNUr.png)

and my code below there

```
 Promise.all([
        faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models'),
        faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
        //faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models')

    ]).then(startVideo());
```

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE1GL.png)

can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

Hi for anyone who are having the same problem in ASP.NET MVC , what i did was first get the latest models in the github https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js under the file weighs and get the latest face-api.min.js under the file named dist after downloading this please rename the followings files in the models , rename it like this face_landmark_68_model-shard1.bin put a bin in every ending of the files please note that only the files like that dont include the jason , after renaming all of that create a folder in wwwroot in in your project name model and put all the models there at the same time copy the face-api.min.js there too and the last step you need to do is rename the path files inside the json so you need to open the models and open json files at the end of the code you will see the path file please rename it and make the same ending .bin like what i said after that you can build the project and its all working .

Additional note : make sure you put the defer script face-api.min.js first before the actual script in your html ..

Comment: Thank you for sharing...
Anyway there is no  need to copy all the files in the root directory if you put the right path in the script.js
e.g.
Promise.all([
  faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('js/faceApi/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('js/faceApi/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('js/faceApi/models'),
  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('js/faceApi/models')
]).then(startVideo)

Answer (score 0):

> GETTING 404 Result on javascript face-api problem

Based on the screenshots of error and folder structure, we can find that the "tiny_face_detector_model-shard1" etc resource that you requests without file extension, which will not be treated as a normal static file request in your ASP.NET Core app.

You can try to add a ".shard" extension for the non extension file, and  change the "path" property to the new file name including the ".shard" extension in  corresponding "..._manifest.json" file.

Reference from: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/issues/131#issuecomment-561738466